# Why do people downvote my working answer?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Someone asks a question along the lines of "my query is not working". I suggest him a solution, and then some people downvote the answer because of a risk of SQL injections.

I did mention "assuming that OP implements **SQL injection protection**" in my answer.

Why do people forget about the solution and downvote my answer for this? Can they just downvote me for a security risk?

Comment: @devpro: Did you just delete your answer because of 1 downvote?

Comment: @simon-klaver undeleted here is my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559812/getting-error-while-updating-mysql-database/34559849#34559849

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems from my point of view that the users downvoting and commenting are particularly not happy with a security risk exposed in your answer.

To me, that seems a legitimate reason to downvote: your answer might be useful to the OP since it solved his problem at hand, but by introducing a huge security risk, OP isn't helped at all. I suggest to update your answer to make it SQL injection safe.

Comment: If I downvote the post .. I try to share reason aswell..... its my ethical responsblty.

Comment: They don't have to. Voting is anonymous. Some people are concerned to be revenge downvoted.

Comment: Also, I read your question more as "can users downvote me for a security risk in my answer", where the answer is *yes*.

Comment: Yes I am asking like that @patrick-hofman

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559812/getting-error-while-updating-mysql-database/34559849#34559849   @patrick-hofman

Comment: There are several reason I could downvote your initial post for, formatting is one of them. And it is an obvious duplicate too.

Comment: my brother I updated the formating and for duplicate dont know. Just tryd to solve issue. Well thnks for support friend

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote so I don't know the reason, but you can't expect for someone to stick along until you have done your work formatting the post, so the downvote might stick even though you've edited it.